# i want to tune the query below

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT GRIRNO,GRIRDATE,CLRD_ON
FROM GRIR_PASS
WHERE APRVD_BY IS NOT NULL and
      grirno not in 
    (select grirno
     from grirmain
     where rcvd_by is not null
    )
ORDER BY
     TO_NUMBER(substr(GRIRNO,instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,1)+1,(instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,2)-instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,1)-1)));
```

Comment: thank you, but it was also taking too much time to execute

Comment: I would recommend you to add a suitable index for that query on the table GRIR_PASS - even consider to add a virtual column for the order by expression

Comment: What happens to the total execution time of the query if you drop the `ORDER BY` clause? Is it about the same or does it run much faster than the version of the query with the `ORDER BY`? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and add this information. In addition, how is the `GRIRNO` column formatted? Please include examples **in the question body** of the data you're processing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use `MINUS` rather than `NOT IN` 
for performance gain for most situations :

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
 SELECT GRIRNO, GRIRDATE, CLRD_ON
  FROM GRIR_PASS
 WHERE APRVD_BY IS NOT NULL
 MINUS
 SELECT GRIRNO, GRIRDATE, CLRD_ON
  FROM GRIR_PASS
 WHERE grirno in (select grirno from grirmain where rcvd_by is not null)
 ) 
 ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(substr(GRIRNO,
                           instr(GRIRNO, '/', 1, 1) + 1,
                           (instr(GRIRNO, '/', 1, 2) -
                           instr(GRIRNO, '/', 1, 1) - 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MINUS instead of not in  for select the GRIRNO involved formmthe tow tables GRIR_PASS  and grirmain

```
  select GRIRNO,GRIRDATE,CLRD_ON 
  from GRIR_PASS 
  inner join  (
    select  GRIRNO 
    FROM GRIR_PASS
    WHERE APRVD_BY IS NOT NULL
    minus 
    select grirno 
    from grirmain
    where rcvd_by is not null
  ) t on t.GRIRNO = GRIR_PASS.GRIRNO
  ORDER BY
       TO_NUMBER(substr(GRIRNO,instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,1)+1,(instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,2)-instr(GRIRNO,'/',1,1)-1)));
```